# Typesignature for functional validate monad in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, monads

I wrote a simple functional validate monad in typescript. To test the behavior, I compose 3 functions and want to lexplore the result. But the ts-compiler show me either an error for typesignature or I get the wrong end-result when I inspect (hover over) my variable where the compose function is stored.

I have tried to play around with typesignature on all functions. But at least one type error is shown up.

You can check out [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYwuCBnApnAvnAMyjTgHIoBDEAEwtIChGsAPSWOYAOxiygIuQ4AygFdkgjBgA8AFQB8ienGVwoWCtQicANgE84AfRgUA5gC44GGFC4mANEpVqNWvYYBuFbSKwWZ9XHoWNnguHj4BHAAxCmBvNVkFBEdlZ00dfSNTCysbTnsU1XV0twNPb184f0Dg6HgYXTAcADUvYFoeRLgAXjhRcSxJLoAfOBi4kQT5JlY6lC0rQlj4nF7EgApynz8ASgtxla7uhXWkLPMyA8msUjsPL224LZxcHYBuGZD5zkWMMQkMD04BtnrsLP0AUcTmdjBdSBDBhhbvcKhZnnh3p85qgfvAiGgAHIibTaCgAI20q2B8k2D0qMj2fX+iMSwyuUwUxzgtIqPV6nGJ2h2cAA-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) and you will see the error on cMap

```
import { compose } from 'ramda'


export interface Success<T> {
    readonly _tag: string,
    readonly _value: T
}
export interface Failure<T> {
    readonly _tag: string,
    readonly _value: T
}
export type Validate<T> = Success<T> | Failure<T>

export const failure = <T>(value: T): Failure<T> => ({ _tag: 'Failure', _value: value });

export const success = <T>(value: T): Success<T> => ({ _tag: 'Success', _value: value });

export const fromNullable = <T>(value: T): Success<T>|Failure<T> => (value == null) ? failure(value) : success(value);

export const isFailure = <T>(ma: Validate<T|T[]>): boolean => (ma._tag === 'Failure') ? true : false;

export const cMap: <T1,T2>(fn: (a: T1) => T2) => (ma: Success<T1>|Failure<T1[]>) => Success<T1>|Failure<T1[]>  = 
    (fn) => (ma) => isFailure(ma) ? ma : fromNullable(fn(ma._value));

export const cChain: <T1,T2>(fn: (a: T1) => T2) => (ma: Validate<T1>) => T2 | Failure<T1> = 
    (fn) => (ma) => isFailure(ma) ? ma : fn(ma._value);


const email = 'test@test.de'

const isEmail = (value: string): Success<string> | Failure<Array<string>> =>
// dummy implementation
(value.length > 3) ? success(value) : failure(['Email is not valid']) 

const findUser = (value: {email: string}) => {
    return Promise.resolve(value)
}

const toObject = (email: string) =>{
    return {email}
 }

const user = compose(
        cChain(findUser),
        cMap(toObject),
        isEmail
        )(email);


console.log(user)
```

Comment: Why `Failure<T1[]>` instead of `Failure<T1>`? Why `Failure<T1>` instead of `Failure`? Why does failure need to be generic?

Comment: First: `Failure<T1[]>` was my last try to get this work. I have tried it with `Failure<T1>` and `Validate<T1>` but as I mention: the endresult is either a compiler error or the result on const user is wrong.
Second: Failure needs to be generic because it can be a string, numer or some other type

Comment: By having the same `Failure` type as the `Success` type, you are too limited. This would mean that e.g. in a `map:: (T1 => T2) => Validate<T1> => Validate<T2>`, you would need to map over both variants, which makes the distinction a bit meaningless. Use two type parameters of your `Validate`, one for the success and one for the error case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually quite simple. The solution is not necessarily so. [I've cleaned up your types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEEkHMDsHsCcCmoAuALAlgZ1AIwDawDGA1gDShYYC2ADvgJ6g32LWLQo4oO2JYBDAGbJaGPpVigA7sgAmsaAHIUAKBCg0AgG7IUU6QIwpQQhKHgDqcgaimEBcgHTqwAZUTI0KFLSwAuECwUAVJYXXghQmknIlhqYABHAFd+FAxFLGAAVgBmAEYAdlyAJgAGXOAePiwieHEUAFokImT4Kl1GoWToInTFRri6WCp+6FVVauQAGVhYEmTaAB4AFQoAaVBEAA8UDjkcEkQGWCFQAWgGCgBRfCxEAF5oRAiAPlAH0E2dvegD0COJzOK1AAH5QCsANrrAC6oH8oFu90mvGQKyM+FWW12+xwFwYkJh70+qlAoAAFOSnNSUAiVgBKD7vbSwDByRk-XEU8nbBH4ijUpzJBEYaAieCgACqjIezNZ7LBUvhoGeEQA3CiJAAxHpEfIfCkCeCQPmXGXvfEaqagACCxpWqKWWpud0eqsQ8GJoC12N+-3JRpNzDFHtt5vOl0VNuVSMQVtRtqwAGEtKKnb6uZCdb18gLqdm9YSYRQAOIZv44Av5QmfdEYTFa17E0mgADeoGhwYBx1O3phCIDxoRdsgDr4TuhRPDI7HiCWs3miyWJY2FHxrzXl3eAF94xJpgJguA-jsAPJCLGcisRglEj4tymC3kQ8MstkcnHXykMU1XUCCgAvEUQwlaUmVAN92RbcFJUhJR8A4SB0CUOEEXdeAJjkRAiHwI1kG6XoxlAMRxx9K9-khQcg3xcN+X-ak7UsBglio39aK3IlyRbQUhARH0ADJExTIxoCdV5VHpAdA2He1HS1SEyincCACVEBQNpoFnCcDyPE9tnPMSiQ1VxEQAOQAEQgEtTNPZTrgmUU9kiUJkDcZIiCIfgsFWd5WxbMkkEcRRGFAAB9EIg2CepoEgMh-IsRAgugELQu0AR8FSOlVG3BzOA9IQXO9DE2jnFZfPiwKFGSphwoESKUGi2KKsSqqUrSjLECynLNWQAA1dK2QEPYfINNyPK8kaAB8ivrEqfImHZaAQEw4mgYJTGKpADR88l2syl8+M20riXecl21qoMlC1I6lAoVL0v2vbkG3eljMW5bQFW9asHczysBwT4dqeulJNAMa-u8srwLOsKIoRJRwa826wuBiCHue16Fu2Jb4BWzITCEeB4lM5J8FwghkEBsrdvRkGEUR-6fMm67ZqQEbZQpJ6Pk+aBSfwRlwQK1nEBpjrGQRH7xv+0XUkx1R3txz78eYLAWYyraqdeclqAEBF+vwQbhrK0HcDmBCLmhnWnAu7nPium6BdQeBUmVArXTe7GPq+laAFkBFoBFVlzFYSi1oRoCkul8nDEPw213XQH1w3SvyV5wwZyHQ+Zo6g9ebPhdWUOyRJMkyXJcO4518NsDVkr48dnXXaJ6gSbJgQKfL6B4+tp76TlhW8bWlbhNFQOVmD0PO8jiFo-A2PLYTpObCN1OY5KUBptrtnx69eLO8rgRq9Vo768VRuEXD7v7rF4zVG9rYdfrA0VDSAABPZgicLClAme-sGuR++ADQy06pQBqopICgwzksKKED3ibxzrAmKJ0TJyGSNQagTAWAIXYJwIaGRxggKcAhGK6BQDvFyI7SWEMQHiw2sLckSgAEYhViqWAJh2psiUIyX+yshCijkJKe4EpPggIRK2NgGIJbgJii9cCflS4JXUvAaAoAAAKzdsCICcEgLAsB8C6FodlXhQ87CnlwAAK2wiYURkj6zSMauaBRpckDKNURIwBOVur3zOJ8IgI8u78L+EIj0mN77UANEQP2tByT6HMVYvoct756gNCREW-9AEUGoGE5WRB16fDSdrCgQgknK2SMI1J4gRbxQyRiOKiion+1ibAeJ1j6T1NLv41MgSBEhPgPSCS5I7H8w1EAA) to expose the problem:

```
const cMap: <T1,T2>(fn: (a: T1) => T2) => (ma: Validate<T1>) => Success<T2>|Failure<T1>|Failure<T2>  = 
    (fn) => (ma) => isFailure(ma) ? ma : fromNullable(fn(ma._value));
```

The problem is that cMap has *three* possible return types: it can already be a failure (Failure), it can succeed (Success) or, critically, *it can fail at the* `fromNullable` *call*. If you don't account for all three possibilities, the compiler will rightly complain that your signature is incomplete.

With the correct types in place, when you start to build your composition you wind up with

```
const f = cChain(findUser);
```

Which the compiler will tell you has a signature

```
const f: (ma: Validate<{
    email: string;
}>) => Promise<{
    email: string;
}> | Failure<{
    email: string;
}>
```

and

```
const m = cMap(toObject);
```

which has signature

```
const m: (ma: Validate<string>) => Failure<string> | Success<{
    email: string;
}> | Failure<{
    email: string;
}>
```

And now it's quite clear why they won't compose together, the result of chain might possibly be a `Failure<string>` and the mapping function expects `Validate<{ email: string }>`. Which is part of why I asked in the comments if failure really needs to be generic: at least from your examples its value property will always be null or undefined except where you explicitly constructed it with a string.

If you constrain Failure to just take an optional string message things get a lot [less messy](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEEkHMDsHsCcCmoAuALAlgZ1AIwDawDGA1gDShYYC2ADvgJ6g32LWLQo4oO2JYBDAGbJaGPpVigA7sgAmsaAHIUAKBCg0AgG7IUU6QIwpQQhKHgDqcgaimEBcgHTqwAZUTI0KFLSwAuECwUAVJYXXghQmknIlhqYABHAFd+FAxFLGAAVgBmAEYAdlyAJgAGXOAePiwieHEUAFokImT4Kl1GoWToInTFRri6WCp+6FVVauQAGVhYEmTaAB4AFQoAaVBEAA8UDjkcEkQGWCFQAWgGCgBRfCxEAF5oRAiAPlAH0E2dvegD0COJzOK1AAH5QCsANrrAC6oH8oFu90mvGQKyM+FWW12+xwFwYkJh70+qlAoAAFOSnNSUAiVgBKD7vbSwDByRk-XEU8nbBH4ijUpzJBEYaAieCgACqjIezNZ7LBUvhoGeEQA3CiJAAxHpEfIfCkCeCQPmXGXvfEaqagACCxpWqKWWpud0eqsQ8GJoC12N+-3JRpNzDFHtt5vOl0VNuVSMQVtRtqwAGEtKKnb6uZCdb18gLqdm9YSYRQAOIZv44Av5QmfdEYTFa17E0mgADeoGhwYBx1O3phCIDxoRdsgDr4TuhRPDI7HiCWs3miyWJY2FHxrzXl3eAF94xJpgJguA-jsAPJCLGcisRglEj4tymC3kQ8MstkcnHXykMU1XUCCgAvEUQwlaUmVAN92RbcFJUhJR8A4SB0CUOEEXdeAJjkRAiHwI1kG6XoxlAMRxx9K9-khQcg3xcN+X-ak7UsBglio39aK3IlyRbQUhARH0ADJExTIxoCdV5VHpAdA2He1HS1SEyincCACVEBQNpoFnCcDyPE9tnPMSiQ1VxEQAOQAEQgEtTNPZTrgmUU9kiUJkDcZIiCIfgsFWd5WxbMkkEcRRGFAAB9EIg2CepoEgMh-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-EcR6D2ZdqA1MrrQU6sBUkZL6BfMueoDQkUQOSWh9D8AUGoC02+RBgGfGGWHCgQh+m32SE4oZ4gRnxTGRiOKR0iAdK6T0zJ9I9krVqamep9imnwHpBJckOSPZAA):

```
interface Success<T> {
    readonly _tag: string,
    readonly _value: T
}

// I've used a class here because it's very easy to
// satisfy the typechecker with instanceof. You don't
// *have* to use a class, it's just easier.
class Failure {
  _tag: string
  _value: string
  constructor (value?: any) {
    this._tag = 'Failure';
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      this._value = value;
    } else {
      this._value = 'undefined or null or unknown value';
    }
  }
}

type Validate<T> = Success<T> | Failure

export const success = <T>(value: T): Success<T> => ({ _tag: 'Success', _value: value });

export const fromNullable = <T>(value: T): Validate<T> => (value == null) ? new Failure() : success(value);

export const isFailure = <T>(ma: Validate<T>): boolean => (ma._tag === 'Failure') ? true : false;

export const cMap: <T1,T2>(fn: (a: T1) => T2) => (ma: Validate<T1>) => Validate<T2>  = 
    (fn) => (ma) => ma instanceof Failure ? ma : fromNullable(fn(ma._value));

export const cChain: <T1,T2>(fn: (a: T1) => T2) => (ma: Validate<T1>) => T2 | Failure = 
    (fn) => (ma) => ma instanceof Failure ? ma : fn(ma._value);


const email = 'test@test.de'

const isEmail = (value: string): Success<string> | Failure =>
// dummy implementation
(value.length > 3) ? success(value) : new Failure('Email is not valid')

const findUser = (value: {email: string}) => {
    return Promise.resolve(value)
}

const toObject = (email: string) =>{
    return {email}
}

const f = cChain(findUser);
const m = cMap(toObject);

const c1 = pipe(isEmail, m);
const c2 = pipe(m, f);

const user = pipe(
    isEmail,
    cMap(toObject),
    cChain(findUser)
)(email);
```

And now you can see user has the expected type of `Promise<{ email: string }>|Failure`. One last aside, generally IIRC [chain should be m => m a ~> (a -> m b) -> m b](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain), and yours returns a plain b at the end instead of `Validate<b>`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't have realized that my implementation of cMap returns three types. Know it's clear why I get some "false" returned output.  Your implementation seems to be a good idea. I think that should work for me. And again, thank you. I was trying to solve this problem for a few days. I will also have a look at the correct implementation for chain.

Comment: @Zantinger you're welcome. In the future when debugging problems like these remember to construct compositions of functions two at a time rather than all at once: it's a lot easier to pinpoint the issue (that's also why I left the intermediates f and m as well as c1 and c2). I sometimes wonder if variadic compose/pipe is actually a bad idea given how hard it makes debugging vs the arity-2 version.